# Why do i getting can't file open error in pycharm even i have the file in same directory

Tags: python, windows, module, pycharm

I'm using pycharm IDE. While running a python file it is showing the following :error:

```
C:\python3.8\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/hruthik/Desktop/Camera/pyhton pactice/file handling.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

but I have the file in same directory. What to do?

[PyCharm Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3KX3.png)

Comment: The message is clear: there is no such file. If you think it exists, double check it, you're certainly wrong...

Comment: I removed the 'python-idle' tag because it is for questions about the IDLE IDE that comes with cpython when tkinter is installed, not for all python IDEs.

Comment: As I can see on the screenshot, there is no such file

Answer (score 1):

it's running another file (file handling.py) not the one you are editing (hi].py)

right-click and choose Run from the context menu